# How to pass data from javascript to rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, coffeescript, relationship

I am using the datatables gem to allow for selection of certain locations for a campaign. Once the selections have been made, I wish to pass that location array, that is in coffee-script, into the campaigns model so that I can then build out the proper relationships in the correct tables.

At present, I am unaware of any process or method for passing an array of data from the coffee-script to the campaigns model. How can this be done?

The present coffee-script (the data is in the array allLcoations):

```
$("#showAllRestaurants").click ->

    allLocations = root.table.rows().data()

    $('#multi_markers').map ->
      handler = Gmaps.build("Google", builders: { Marker: CustomMarkerBuilder })
      handler.buildMap
        internal:
          id: "multi_markers"
      , ->
        for aLocation in allLocations
          markers = handler.addMarkers([
            {
              lat: aLocation[9]
              lng: aLocation[10]
              custom_marker:     "<img src='/assets/images/redDotMarker.png' width='40' height='40'>"
              custom_infowindow: "Store Number: #{aLocation[1]}; Address: #{aLocation[2]}, #{aLocation[3]}; Major Bidding City: #{aLocation[6]}"
            }
          ])

        handler.bounds.extendWith markers
        handler.fitMapToBounds()
        return
```

Comment: when you say model, do you mean on the rails side, as in an ActiveRecord model?

Answer (score 0):

You can either write coffeescript in your view directly or create a new file.

If you wish to write it directly in the view. All you have to do is, insert `:coffeescript` before the code for HAML. For HTML, insert `<coffeescript> code ... </coffescript>`

In HAML

```
:coffeescript
  $("#showAllRestaurants").click ->

    allLocations = root.table.rows().data()

    $('#multi_markers').map ->
      handler = Gmaps.build("Google", builders: { Marker: CustomMarkerBuilder })
      handler.buildMap
        internal:
          id: "multi_markers"
      , ->
        for aLocation in allLocations
          markers = handler.addMarkers([
            {
              lat: aLocation[9]
              lng: aLocation[10]
              custom_marker:     "<img src='/assets/images/redDotMarker.png' width='40' height='40'>"
              custom_infowindow: "Store Number: #{aLocation[1]}; Address: #{aLocation[2]}, #{aLocation[3]}; Major Bidding City: #{aLocation[6]}"
            }
          ])

        handler.bounds.extendWith markers
        handler.fitMapToBounds()
        return
```

In HTML

```
<coffeescript>
  $("#showAllRestaurants").click ->

      allLocations = root.table.rows().data()

      $('#multi_markers').map ->
        handler = Gmaps.build("Google", builders: { Marker: CustomMarkerBuilder })
        handler.buildMap
          internal:
            id: "multi_markers"
        , ->
          for aLocation in allLocations
            markers = handler.addMarkers([
              {
                lat: aLocation[9]
                lng: aLocation[10]
                custom_marker:     "<img src='/assets/images/redDotMarker.png' width='40' height='40'>"
                custom_infowindow: "Store Number: #{aLocation[1]}; Address: #{aLocation[2]}, #{aLocation[3]}; Major Bidding City: #{aLocation[6]}"
              }
            ])

          handler.bounds.extendWith markers
          handler.fitMapToBounds()
          return
</coffeescript>
```